# What are the different endings in Revolution 60 and how are they achieved?

Tags: ios, revolution-60

The game mentions different endings based on your performance and choices. What are the endings and how do you get them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm Brianna Wu, the developer of this game. There are 24 ending permutations. 
First variable: Professional or Rogue
Second variable: Align with Minuete, Amelia or Neutral
Third Variable: Does a major character live or die?
Fourth Variable: Proficiency Pass or Fail. It's set at different levels depending on difficulty.

I won't spoil the endings, but I will say there's no one good ending. Either you fail your mission, or you partially succeed. There are no perfect resolutions in this universe.

I'd also say, as the creator, the ending I consider best is R M L P. I think P A L P is the most interesting opening in R62 though.